# Post request in Rails controller for instagram authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instagram

So, I am trying to allow users of my app to sign in with Instagram and then use their access_token to perform requests to the Instagram API.

I had a look a the omniauth-instagram rails gem, but it doesn't seem like it works with the access token and I cannot seem to send a redirect uri.

So, now I'm trying to do the authorization myself, taking the omniauth gems as an example. So far, I have a link to the Instagram API in my html: `<a href="https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=       <%=ENV["INSTAGRAM_KEY"]%>&redirect_uri=<%= "http://localhost:3000/auth/instagram/request_token" %>&response_type=code">Instagram</a>`

The redirect-uri then comes to this method:

```
def request_token
    @code = params[:code]
    uri = URI.parse('https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token')
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
    request.set_form_data({
      "client_id" => ENV["INSTAGRAM_KEY"],
      "client_secret" => ENV["INSTAGRAM_SECRET"],
      "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
      "redirect_uri" => "http://localhost:3000/auth/instagram/access",
      "code" => @code
      })      
  end
```

I required net/https. Still the only thing that happens is that the view that is associated with request_token is shown. Nothing seems to be happening with the http request. I'm very new to using net/http. The things that I'm missing are probably very obvious, but I just don't see it. Some help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set up the request, but now you need to execute it. You do that with `Net::HTTP.start`. Here's an example from [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-How+to+use+Net-3A-3AHTTP):

```
uri = URI('http://www.example.com/todo.cgi')
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
req.set_form_data('from' => '2005-01-01', 'to' => '2005-03-31')

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|
  http.request(req)
end

case res
when Net::HTTPSuccess, Net::HTTPRedirection
  # OK
else
  res.value
end
```

Many people find `Net::HTTP` unnecessarily baroque, so you could also consider some HTTP gems like [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) or [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty), which have terser APIs. Continuing with `Net::HTTP`, you might find this [cheat sheet](https://github.com/augustl/net-http-cheat-sheet) handy.